# Complex query involving average of a column over the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this one, which name is tv_v2.tv_momentum

```
 tv_date            instrument_name                        factor

2019-07-22  cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a2cc48    50.1228599355797
2019-07-23  cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a2cc5a    50.0851750766468
2019-07-24  cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a2cc48    50.0474332287848
2019-07-25  cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a2cc31    50.0096342626235
2019-07-26  cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a2cc48    50.312332423432343
2019-07-27  cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a2cc48    23.424234234234
2019-07-28  cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a77777    15.33333332332323
2019-07-29  cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a2cc48    66.3333333333333
2019-07-30  cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a2cc4f    77.322332323223
2019-07-31  cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a2cc4s    50
```

I would like to get the average factor per instrument per month and the factor of just the last day of the month..can you help me in designing the query?

```
YEAR  MONTH  END_OF_MONTH_DAY   INSTRUMENT_NAME    AVERAGE_FACTOR_OVER_THE_MONTH  END_OF_THE_MONTH_FACTOR

2019    7      31-7     cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a2cc48        50.11              50
2019    8      31-8     cbc267f7-6ace-4357-a803-7aaf96a2cc48        33                 56
```

Comment: database version?  what's your table name?

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you can use window functions. If you're using 5.x you need to write two queries, one to get the last row of the month, another to get the month average, and join them.

Comment: Sorry the name of the table is tv_v2.tv_momentum

Comment: and the database version?  `select version();`

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio      15.0.18330.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)      16.100.37971.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      15.0.19040.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      10.0.14393

Comment: So are you using SQL Server or MySQL?????  They're completely different products.

Comment: @eric is from Microsoft Azure, the select version() does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select year(tv_date), month(tv_date), max(tv_date), 
       instrument_name,
       avg(factor),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then factor end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(tv_date), month(tv_date)  order by tv_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by year(tv_date), month(tv_date), instrument_name;
```

Comment: I'd just use `first_value(factor) over (partition by extract(year_month from tv_date) order by tv_date desc)`, not row_number

Comment: is t.* the name of the table?

Comment: 'extract' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @ysth: you can't use `first_value(factor) over(...)` in this aggregation query if `factor` is not part of the `group by` clause.

Comment: @user3139149: this function does not exist in SQL Server, which the question was finally tagged with (it started as MySQL). Just replace `partition by extract(year_month from tv_date)` with `partition by year(tv_date), month(tv_date)`

Comment: @user3139149 . . . `t` is the name of the table.  `t.*` refers to all the columns.  As GMB points out, the question was originally tagged MySQL which *does* support the SQL standard function `extract()`.